# How can I register an AvaloniaProperty to set control's focus and bind in viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am developing an **avalonia** wpf application, and I registered an AttachedProperty "IsFocused" as following:

```
public class FocusExtension
{
    public static readonly AttachedProperty<bool> IsFocusedProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.RegisterAttached<Control, bool>("IsFocused", typeof(FocusExtension));

    public static bool GetIsFocused(Control element)
    {
        return element.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFocused(Control element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
        OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(element, value);
    }

    private static void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(
        Control element,
        bool e)
    {
        if (e)
        {
            element.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

And apply it in xaml like that:

```
  <Button Content="Test" u:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding SomeBoolPropertyInViewModel}"/>
```

But it seems not work when "SomeBoolPropertyInViewModel" is set to be true from my ViewModel,

Could someone give me an example or hint to implement this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that `SetIsFocused` will be called, as `element.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value)` may be called directly. So you have to add a handler for the property changed event, in the static constructor:

```
static FocusExtension()
{
    IsFocusedProperty.Changed.AddClassHandler<Control>(OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged);
}

private static void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(
    Control element,
    AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        element.Focus();
    }
}
```